# Varchar and int columns join in sql

Tags: sql-server, nvarchar, truncated

I tried this query

```
insert into Dimension_DDTU (BI_Id, BI_Name, DBI_Id, dBI_Name)
    select
        ds.BI_ID,
        dvo.name,
        ds.BI_Id + '' + dm.DBI_Id as DBI_Id,
        dso.dname
    from 
        Census.dbo.SMaster sm
    full outer join 
        C.dbo.dis dso on dso.did = sm.did
    full outer join  
        C.dbo.Div dvo on dvo.dsid = dso.diid
    full outer join 
        b.dbo.DMap ds on ds.DOp_Id = dso.did
    full outer join 
        b.dbo.DsMap dm on dm.DOp_Id = sm.did
```

here `BI_Id,DBI_Id` data type is nvarchar(50) because I am storing values like this (001,002 ...)

and other columns which is in join are all int data type except

```
BI_Id and DBI_Id
```

this shows an error

> String or binary data would be truncated.

Comment: what is the data type for the source columns? are they also of varchar type?

Comment: check update please .. the columns which is in join are int data type execpt BI_Id and DBI_Id these are varchar(50) because i am storing data in these columns like this 001,002 etc

Comment: but BI_id and DBI_Id are there on both source and destination. so it's little confusing. Can you share the full structure of Dimension_DDTU

Comment: @seesharp whts lenght of `DBI_Id` field check & confirm wht ur passing data within it's lenght ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error says you are having troubles with insertion.

Here: `Dimension_DDTU (BI_Id, BI_Name, DBI_Id, dBI_Name)` one of column sized is not enough for storing inserted values.

My chrystal ball says it is `Dimension_DDTU.DBI_Id` which is of same `varchar(50)` size whilst must be `varchar(100)` at least to accept `ds.BI_Id + '' + dm.DBI_Id` (`varchar(50)` + `varchar(50)`).

If there will be a separator between those IDs then you should increaze size by size of that separator as well.